# Как конвертировать текстовой формат в дату?

Tags: sql, sas

Штука в том, что данные заданы как:

MYYYY_MM, где первая буква M - в прямом смысле буква M, YYYY - год, MM - месяц.

Однако, для октября - декабря данные заданы как, к примеру: M2020_10; в случае с месяцами раньше данные заданы как M2020_1, M2020_2 и т.д. (лишь одна цифра после нижнего подчёркивания).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно конвертировать текстовой формат в date9. отсюда?

Обрезал уже букву M через

substr (MONTH,2,7)

и даже попробовал вырезать _ , но дальше упёрся в разное кол-во цифр после этого знака...

Answer (score 0):

Для MySQL есть функция `STR_TO_DATE(str,fmt)`

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select STR_TO_DATE('M2020_10', 'M%Y_%m');
+-----------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('M2020_10', 'M%Y_%m') |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2020-10-00                        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Тут день 00 - отсутствует, эта дата подойдет для операций сравнения. Но для арифметики нужно установить день. (но наш вопрос про SAS вроде)

Для POSTGRESQL есть `to_date(str,fmt)`

```
select to_date('M2020_2','M%Y_%MM');
```

С MySQL давно не работал, возможно он уже поддерживает `to_date`.

Читаю про SAS - какая-то странная штуковина.... но есть доки и формум.(правда проверить не на чем)

Попробуй определить новый формат данных:

```
picture mydatetime ( default=8)
low-high = 'M%Y_%m'   (datatype=datetime)
;
```

И через input форматнуть

```
input('M2020_10',mydatetime.)
```

Comment: select STR_TO_DATE('M2020_1', 'M%Y_%m') => 2019-12-31

Comment: @splash58 от того что день равен нулю - то последнее число прошлого месяца. думаю просто закостылить там +1 день по месту

Comment: да, конечно. тока это надо написать

Comment: @splash58 - у меня нормально сработало - какая у вас версия MySQL?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acc36/8

Comment: В SAS работает PROC SQL, не читаются команды вроде str_to_date и to_date...

Через формат попробовал сделать, но в столбце теперь одни точки.

Может быть через DATA step можно сделать как?

Comment: Верхние строчки для примера, а вот sas попробовать неначем... наверное Вам лучше к ним на форум

Answer (score 0):

Справился через:

```
MYYYY_MM -> (substr(MONTH,2,4)||substr(MONTH,7,2)) -> input (MONTH, yymmn6.) as MONTH format = date9.
```